# Full width div disappears on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what I'm trying to do is the following: Make a full width image as the intro of the website and then, when the user scrolls, the image slowly slides away. I already get everything pretty much done, my question it's only about one detail. So here's the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var introEl = $('div.intro'), //where intro is the full width div
            introHeadingH = introEl.find('h1').height(),
            windowH = $(window).height();

        introEl.css('padding', (windowH - introHeadingH)/2 + 'px 0');

        $(document).on('scroll', function() {
            introEl.slideUp(1000, function() { $(document).off('scroll'); });
        });


    })();
</script>
```

That way, whenever the scroll down is activated, the image proceed to the "slideUp" but with the limitation of the "1000" ms. Since I'm not very familiar with javascript yet, I'm asking for help to make the image disappear completely only when the user is done scrolling. Here's an example: http://hightidenyc.com
I can post the rest of the code if you say it's needed, but I think it's just a javascript case so thanks everybody!!

*///* update *///*
So, I'm gonna let the work that was made with the help of @bfmags here for future researches 
https://jsfiddle.net/flavioneto/13b1oktL/1/
It was added also "background-attachment: fixed" to give a cooler effect on the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the example they're just removing the header div element after the image is scrolled out

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        windowH = $(window).height();
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>windowH)
        {
            $('div.intro').remove();
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
```

you could also change display style to none, or change the css class of the div to a style not containing the image as background (and correct height / other)

*updated with @op_exchanger code https://jsfiddle.net/yekL3xjq/1/

Comment: hey, really thankful for your response! forgive for my ignorance, I plan to study js as soon as possible. but still, in the code you posted, the "remove" of the div is dependant of the 1000ms clause, and not of the action of the scroll itself. there is another way this could be coded? sorry if I miss something in your response and just didn't give +1 cause I doesn't have reputation enough yet haha

Comment: hi, I created this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/obgbezLu/
> you can edit it, save and add the new link to your question
> in the answer, the element is being removed after the slideup animation

Comment: really appreciate your effort, it helps me a lot! so, i could make this jsfiddle that seems a little closer of what i needed https://jsfiddle.net/flavioneto/yekL3xjq/
as you can see, the div disappears after scroll it's done, but the page left jumps with the quantity of scroll that has been done, instead of remain in the top position. any suggestions about this?